# How can I call a function contained in a controller, from a .factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my code I am trying to have a generic function, that when I pass the name of my function that is in my controller and run from a factory.

```
app.factory('myfactory', function () {

    return {
      create: function (name_of_function) {

        angular.element(document.body).append('<button ng-click="'+name_of_function+'">trigger my function</button>') 

          return "";
      }
    };
  });
```

create: function (**name_of_function**) {

I am passing the name of my function so that when I click on the button execute my function that is in the controller.

```
function HelloCtrl($scope, myfactory) {
  //name of my function
  myfactory.create("myfunction()");
  $scope.myfunction=function(){
    alert("it works")
  }
}
```

How can do it that?

https://plnkr.co/edit/z6s129TQ82REyCDscJTq?p=preview

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, code that manipulates the DOM should be encapsulated in a custom directive. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

Your factory could return html string that you want to append it to body. In controller you can append html to body. before appending you need to compile your html string.

```js
//angular.js Concrete Factory example

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

// Concrete Factory
app.factory('myfactory', function () {

    
  return {
    create: function (name_of_function) {
  
         return '<button ng-click="'+name_of_function+'">trigger my function</button>';

      }
  };
});


function HelloCtrl($scope, myfactory,$compile) {
 
  
  angular.element(document.body).append($compile(myfactory.create("myfunction()"))($scope))


  $scope.myfunction=function(){
    alert("it works")
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.2/angular.js"></script>
  
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
    
  </div>
  <br />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. but I think this solution has a problem, and is that the generated html, will be saved in the body of the document, and if I navigate in more views will always be there written and written n times as I use it. also I think it will be somewhat uncomfortable to always write this long line from the controller. maybe there is a better way.

Comment: then try with directives. directives may help you

Comment: I do not know how to do it, I do not know how to apply it in my case. I would like to do something like call a function inside my controller for what I need.